# How to achieve this sql server replication scenario?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I want to achieve below illustrated scenario via sql server replication.

[image]

Client A and Client B are client databases containing same article Table A. This article needs to be published by Client A and Client B whose changes need to be merged at the server (direction of arrows represent data flow).

Server is the destination database where article Table A should contain the changes made by both Client A and Client B. The trio consisting of Server, Client A and Client B are running Sql Server 2008 R2.

This is what I've tried in vain. Made Client A and Client B publishers and initially subscribed Server to Client A (went well). Next I tried subscribing Server to Client B (went haywire, found this msdn [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172911%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) where I figured out the reason behind the failure )

I still need to achieve the above diagrammed scenario. Is this even possible? If yes, any ideas how?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this type of topology is known as the [Central Subscriber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256116%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) Model.  To make this work you should horizontally partition your published data, utilize static row filters, and set the **Action if name is in use** article property to **Delete data. If article has a row filter, delete only data that matches the filter**.

The MSDN article does not detail the implementation very well but I have covered it in [Central Subscriber Model Explained](http://www.sqlrepl.com/sql-server/central-subscriber-model-explained/).